# how to display different images on different infowindow

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

basically the problem is when I open any marker, the infowindow that appears always have the same image, but with the title and snippet no problem.

I know not specific to each marker a different image, but do not know how.
(The image are in the folder drawer)

This is my code:
**Fragmentavtivity.java**

```
public class Fragment17 extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment17, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

final LatLng Initial = new LatLng(-34.673009, -58.474111);

final LatLng FADU = new LatLng(-34.542163, -58.443716);

final LatLng UNO = new LatLng(-34.524924, -58.576421);
final LatLng DOS = new LatLng(-34.755415, -58.577794);


GoogleMap googlemap;

    googlemap  = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map17)).getMap();

    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Initial, 10);
    googlemap.animateCamera(update);

    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(FADU).title("FADU").snippet("Facultad de Arquitectura, Diseño y Urbanismo").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(UNO).title("TEOREMA").snippet("san matin 1245"));
    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DOS).title("El Mundo del Acrilico").snippet("san benito 2144/"));


    googlemap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

     @Override
     public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

         View v = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);

         TextView titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
         TextView direccion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.direccion);
         ImageView imagen = ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen));

         titulo.setText(marker.getTitle());
         direccion.setText(marker.getSnippet());
         imagen.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.teorema));

         return v;

     }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
 });
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

 }
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map17));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();        
}
```

and the **infowindow.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="99dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>


<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/direccion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**and another question:**

as I do for each infowindow of each marker, open a diferent fragment when clicked.

thanks.

Comment: You do not need to change the title to (SOLVED). SO will handle this by itself (yellow number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is that you just put a single image to the infoWindow, if you want to have different images you can put the Marker and the Image resource in the `HashMap` structure, `Marker` as the key and the `image resource` as the value of the HashMap.

**example:**

```
@Override
 public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

     View v = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);

     TextView titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
     TextView direccion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.direccion);
     ImageView imagen = ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen));

     titulo.setText(marker.getTitle());
     direccion.setText(marker.getSnippet());

     if(yourhashMap.get(marker) != null)
        imagen.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(yourhashMap.get(marker)));

     return v;

 }
```

`if(yourhashMap.get(marker) != null)` it will check if the Marker is already in the HashMap.

`(getResources().getDrawable(yourhashMap.get(marker)));` It will get the value of the HashMap which is the resource of the image

**sample:**

create a hashmap:

```
private HashMap<Marker, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();
```

Every time you add a marker to the map add it to the hashmap

```
    Marker marker = new MarkerOptions().position(FADU).title("FADU").snippet("Facultad de Arquitectura, Diseño y Urbanismo").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
    googlemap.addMarker(marker);
    hash.put(marker, R.drawable.the drawable if the marker);
```

**editted:**

```
    public class Fragment17 extends SherlockFragment {

    private HashMap<Marker, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment17, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

final LatLng Initial = new LatLng(-34.673009, -58.474111);

final LatLng FADU = new LatLng(-34.542163, -58.443716);

final LatLng UNO = new LatLng(-34.524924, -58.576421);
final LatLng DOS = new LatLng(-34.755415, -58.577794);


GoogleMap googlemap;

    googlemap  = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map17)).getMap();

    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Initial, 10);
    googlemap.animateCamera(update);

    Marker marker1 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(FADU).title("FADU").snippet("Facultad de Arquitectura, Diseño y Urbanismo").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    hash.put(marker1, R.drawable.the drawable if the marker);

    Marker marker2 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(UNO).title("TEOREMA").snippet("san matin 1245"));
    hash.put(marker2, R.drawable.the drawable if the marker);

    Marker marker3 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DOS).title("El Mundo del Acrilico").snippet("san benito 2144/"));
    hash.put(marker3, R.drawable.the drawable if the marker);

    googlemap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

     @Override
     public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

     View v = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);

     TextView titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
     TextView direccion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.direccion);
     ImageView imagen = ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen));

     titulo.setText(marker.getTitle());
     direccion.setText(marker.getSnippet());

     if(yourhashMap.get(marker) != null)
        imagen.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(yourhashMap.get(marker)));

     return v;

 }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
 });
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

 }
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map17));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();        
}
```

Comment: but in this example, in what moment I specify the image?
for example I have Image1.png for the infowindow of marker1, and image2.png for the infowindow of marker2

Comment: @user3571227 when you add the marker to the map you then add the marker to the hashmap

Comment: and a example of hashmap? i never used really

Comment: I could not get fix this with the hashmap, if you give me a specific example for my particular case would understand better.
sorry for the late

Comment: Thank you men, now i know my mistake